# Robocopy or Batch file to copy entire FOLDER to every profile's %localappdata% please

Tags: batch-file, windows-server

So I'm very new at batch files but have used command line for many purposes though not on the scale that I currently need....

My issue is that I've installed an application on one of our servers (actually 5 servers ..1 main and 4 additional but nearly identical servers) and I've discovered this application writes a folder into the \appdata\local\ directory that it will give an error upon running if ran by one of the client users on the server because they do not have write privileges to the C:\ drive.

So......I'v tested and confirmed that application runs fine if I just copy over the folder into the %LOCALAPPDATA% of the profile i'm testing...thing is...there is a LOT of profiles on just 1 of the servers and I don't want to have to copy this folder manually to all profiles on all 5 servers...will take me all night...

Can someone please help me with a 100% working code for doing this in a batch file? I've read post after post and no one else seems to have this exact issue OR they are wanting specific files copied and not the entire folder/subfolder as I need and I'm extremely reticent to go modifying one of the other answers because I don't know enough to be sure I don't make a time consuming mistake...

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I know you are looking for a batch file, but I think you can solve this very quickly with powershell.

```
$source = "C:\temp"
$servers = "Server1","Server2","Server3"

foreach($node in $servers)
{
    $TargetFolders = Resolve-Path "\\$node\C$\Users\*\AppData\Local"

    foreach($destination in $TargetFolders)
    {
        Robocopy "$source" "$destination" /e /r:0 /w:0
    }
}
```

Test this out before you run it on a production system. I typed it up without testing it myself.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Perhaps I focused too much on the server side in my question...the thing is...there isn't necessarily the same user profile on all servers...some are on all servers but others are only permitted to log in to a specific server and do not access the others. I'm fine with using powershell but if I have to input each profile's name and run the command over and over and over I don't think I'm going to be saving much time over just dragging and dropping via windows explorer. Is there a way I can send it to all profiles on the server and then just go to each server and run?

Comment: Do you see that line that has the resolve-path command? It has a wild card in it so it will enumerate all profiles on that system. This code is checking each server, getting a list of appdata\local folders, then copying the data to them. So this code as is, will deploy that folder to every profile on servers 1-3 by running the script once.

Comment: I see. Yeah I was wondering if that would be the case or not, thanks! I'll try this out on my local and see if it holds water^^

Comment: Quick question - For the server names...I believe I would have to use their UNC path (i.e. "\\server1\") to be able to access them but will that still work with powershell? If not how would I modify that to just be for a single server (the one i'm logged into at the time)? Logging in via RDP client by the way...terminal services enviro.

Comment: is it as simple as: "Robocopy C$\Users\myprofile\desktop\foldername C$\Users\ *\AppData\Local" Can I just run that? o.O

Comment: Robocopy does not understant the wildcard but : resolve-path "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local" | %{Robocopy "C:\Users\myprofile\desktop\foldername" $_ /e} should work